# Beautiful soup getting name of <a> element within a div

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm using Beautiful Soup for the first time, and I'm trying to get values of specific element in the webpage.

For example, in this code snippet:

```
<div class="otg-vendor-name"><a class="otg-vendor-name-link"     href="http://www.3brotherskitchen.com" target="_blank">3 Brothers Kitchen</a></div>
```

I wish to get "3 Brothers Kitchen" from the  tag within the .

So far, I've tried something which doesn't seem to work:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url    = "http://someurl"
def get_all_vendors():
   try:
      web_page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
      soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page)
      c = []
      c.append(soup.findAll("div", {"class":'otg-vendor-name'}).contents)
    print c

   except urllib2.HTTPError:
   print("HTTPERROR!")

   except urllib2.URLError:
   print("URLERROR!")

   return c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by a [`CSS selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('div.otg-vendor-name > a.otg-vendor-name-link')[0].text
```

Or, via [`find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find):

```
soup.find('div', class_='otg-vendor-name').find('a', class_='otg-vendor-name-link').text
```

---

Update (Using `requests` and providing `User-Agent` header):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://offthegridsf.com/vendors#food'

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36'}

    session.get(url)

    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    print soup.select('div.otg-vendor-name > a.otg-vendor-name-link')[0].text
    print soup.find('div', class_='otg-vendor-name').find('a', class_='otg-vendor-name-link').text
```

Comment: It's giving me the error 'NoneType' object is not callable -- how is it NoneType when the elements clearly exist on the webpage?

Comment: @newenthusiast could you share a link to an actual website? Thanks.

Comment: @newenthusiast interesting, both options work for me. Could be a difference between the underlying parsers BeautifulSoup uses, try to replace `soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page)` with `soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'html.parser')` or `soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'html5lib')` or `soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'lxml')`.

Comment: None of these things worked for me. :( I wonder what's wrong.